# Apply certain condition on specific rows in SQL statement

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with following columns

(name : varchar), (mydate : DATE), (endtime : TIME)

I'm trying to get specific rows based on the following conditions:

1. mydate is within a certain range
2. mydate > date(NOW())
3. endTime > time(NOW()), this should apply only to "todays" date rows

The problem is with endTime. For example, consider the following data

1. apples 2011-02-01 21:00:00
2. orange 2011-03-02 10:00:00
3. grapes 2011-05-10 11:00:00

If the inputs to the query are

1. range: 2011-01-01 to 2011-04-01
2. date(NOW()) : 2011-01-01
3. time(NOW()) : 20:00:00

Consider the query

```
SELECT name FROM mytable
WHERE mydate BETWEEN  '2011-01-01' AND '2011-04-01'
AND date >= DATE(NOW()) 
AND endTime > TIME(NOW())
```

The query results only  'apples'. But the correct result is 'apples' and 'orange'.
The problem being condition: endTime > time(NOW()), this should apply only to "todays" date rows.

I dont want to UNION, as my original query is big.
Is there a way we can apply condition to certain rows only.

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM mytable
 WHERE mydate BETWEEN  '2011-01-01' AND '2011-04-01'
   AND ADDTIME(mydate, endtime) > NOW()
```

The [ADDTIME function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) will allow you to combine the DATE and TIME value(s) into a single DATETIME, which you can then use against NOW()/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Frankly, the additional criteria is redundant...

Answer (score 1):

Try making it so that it only checks endTime in the case that the date is on the boundary.

```
SELECT name FROM mytable
WHERE mydate BETWEEN  '2011-01-01' AND '2011-04-01'
AND (date > DATE(NOW()) 
OR (date = DATE(NOW()) AND endTime > TIME(NOW())))
```

Comment: Thank you mdarwi for the solution. It exactly fits the condition. :)